# Simple Batch String Comparison with DisableDelayedExpansion

Tags: batch-file

Sorry if this is so simple, but I just can't get to "success".

```
@echo off
pushd d:
for /f "tokens=1-5*" %%1 in ('vol') do (
  set vol=%%6 & goto done
)
:done
echo ~%vol%~ & pause
if %vol% == "RKO1 " (
echo success
)
pause
EXIT /b
```

the `echo ~%vol%~` line is just to check that vol is really being set to "`RKO1`" (it is).

I'm trying to do this without going into enabledelayedexpansion.

Thx

Comment: You need quotes around both things you're comparing. Give me a bit while I find the question this is a duplicate of.

Comment: You use letters not numbers in a FOR loop. See `for /?`.

Comment: @Mark - You can technically use any ASCII characters at all, it's just _far_ easier to use letters.

Comment: Thank you so much SomethingDark. For some reason in all my coding I never knew to enclose both sides within double quotes. That solved it. I'll updated the original post to reflect the correct solution.

Comment: @RKO, I rolled back your edit, because when you fix the problem in your question the whole thread and also the link to the duplicate one wouldn't make sense anymore then...

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't thinking clearly so early in the morning.